# How to adjust character height when playing seated in closed VR with MRTK?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, mrtk

I am creating a VR application with mrtk 2.1 and want to have the User on the same height when playing seated or standing.
When Playing seated the camera is too low.

I could adjust the height of the MixedRealityPlayspace which contains the MainCamera, but that resets after using the teleport function.
Additionally learned from this [GitHub Post](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/5966), that there is an Offset between the MainCamera and MixedRealityPlayspace which is not accessible via mrtk so calculating the right height would be difficult.
This just does not seem like the right approach.

How can I make sure that the User is always on the right head height in game even when playing seated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i found a solution that works for me.
I use the following code to move the mixedRealityPlayspace up or down to achieve the wanted player height.(if you want to use this make sure to tag your mixedRealityPlayspace GameObject "Player")

```
var mixedRealityPlayspace = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")[0].transform;
var camHeight = mainCamera.transform.position.y;
var adjustement =wantedPlayerHeight-camHeight ;
mixedRealityPlayspace.position= new Vector3(mixedRealityPlayspace.position.x,mixedRealityPlayspace.position.y+adjustement, mixedRealityPlayspace.position.z);
```

I call this on ones on the start of my Scene and in the OnTeleportCompleted Event described in this Dokumentation for the [MRTK Teleport system](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/TeleportSystem/Overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've gone ahead and filed the following feature request:
https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/6786

An untested workaround may be the following:

1. Create logic that instantiates a new GameObject at runtime.
2. Set the new GameObject's parent to be the MixedRealityPlayspace.
3. Set the new GameObject to be the parent of your main camera
4. Apply your desired offset as a transform to this new GameObject.

Talking with different MRTK Contributors, its felt that you may need to do this transform configuration at runtime. Trying to do this in the editor/in the scene hierarchy may encounter problems because folks were unsure whether or not the main camera's parent gets set as the MixedRealityPlayspace regardless of whether or not the main camera is a grandchild of the MixedRealityPlayspace.

Comment: Moving the Camera inside the MixedRealityPlayspace will cause the Pointers to be miss aligned with the camera. I found moving the whole MixedRealityPlayspace works better.